# Add row and td element and a checkbox in the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have the following table structure

```
<form method=POST  class='form leftLabels'>
<table >
<tr >
<th >Code:</th>
<td ><input type='text' name='f[id]'  size='60'  value='10'  /></td>
</tr>
<tr ><th >Name:</th>
<td ><input type='text' name='f[name]'  size='60'  value='Aa'  /></td>
</tr>
// <<<< Here I would like to add a row
<tr >
<td  class=' nogrid buttonsClass'><button type=submit>Save</button>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

The row that I am trying to add should have the following html:

```
<tr>
<th> Delete the record?</th>
<td><input type='checbox' name='delete' value=1></td>
</tr>
```

I have the following Javascript / jQuery code:

```
var trCnt=0;
                $('table tr').each(function(){
                    trCnt++;
                });
                rowToInsertCheckbox = trCnt - 1;
                
                $('table').after(rowToInsertCheckbox).append(
                    $(document.createElement('tr')),
                    $(document.createElement('td').html('Delete the record'),
                    $(document.createElement('td').html('Checkbox here?')),
                );
```

which does find the right row after which the insert should be done, but the code does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`after()` adds the new content after the target element, but *outside* it. `tr` need to be inside the table. In addition you need to append the `td` to the `tr`, not the table.

To place the new `tr` in your target position you can select the last `tr` in the table and use `insertBefore()`, like this:

```js
let $newRow = $('<tr />').insertBefore('table tr:last');
$('<td>Delete the record?</td>').appendTo($newRow);
$('<td><input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1"></td>').appendTo($newRow);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" class="form leftLabels">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Code:</th>
      <td><input type="text" name="f[id]" size="60" value="10" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Name:</th>
      <td><input type="text" name="f[name]" size="60" value="Aa" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="nogrid buttonsClass"><button type="submit">Save</button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to locate the row after which the content should be added is:

```
 var tr = $("th").filter(function () {
                return $(this).text() == "Name:";
            }).closest("tr");
```

Then add the row:

```
$(tr).after("<tr><th> Delete the record?</th><td><input type='checkbox' name='delete' value=1></td></tr>");
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var tr = $("th").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == "Name:";
  }).closest("tr");

  $(tr).after("<tr><th>Delete the record?</th>" +
    "<td><input type='checkbox' name='delete' value=1></td>" +
    "</tr>");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method=POST class='form leftLabels'>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Code:</th>
      <td><input type='text' name='f[id]' size='60' value='10' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Name:</th>
      <td><input type='text' name='f[name]' size='60' value='Aa' /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class=' nogrid buttonsClass'><button type=submit>Save</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```